# How to make text appear under div without moving other items in list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

I have a slight issue with my design. I currently only know how to use CSS/HTML and I would like to add a bit of "pzazz" into a design of mine. This being said , I have been looking at jQuery snippets from others who have tried to do something similar. The text appears under when the other item is hovered on however , the other items in the list move down , even if they all have the same text but since the display:none until it's hovered on , it's as if it isn't there.

These pictures should explain far better than I can.

The two different states :

http://gyazo.com/6f736e7ef79409dbd3398facb03dcf5c.png

Just to clarify ; it is the other boxes that move down. The box with the acorn stays in the same location.

In case you wish to see the code which I used , you can do so here :

http://codepen.io/redhotfusion/pen/ipocE

Here is the CSS bit :

```
.t_s_ul {

list-style-type:none;
width:90%;
padding-left:5px;
margin-left:-10px;
margin:0 auto;

}


.t_s_li {

  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  border:4px white solid;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin:5px;
  position:relative;


}
.t_s_li:hover{

  transition:1s;
  background-color:white;

}

.type_icon {

  background:url("http://i.imgur.com/xix8EC9.png");
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:100%;
  margin-left:-2px;

}

.type_icon:hover{

   transition:1s;
   cursor:pointer;
   background:url("http://i.imgur.com/e1IONg2.png");


}

.course_type_text {

  width:75px;
  color:white;
  font-size:0.85em;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:0.5em;
  margin-left:-0.15em;
  font-family:"Open Sans" , arial;
  font-weight:400;
```

The HTML :

```
<ul class="t_s_ul">

    <li class="t_s_li">
      <div class="type_icon"></div>
      <DIV class="course_type_text">Course One</DIV>
    </li>
    <li class="t_s_li"></li>
    <li class="t_s_li"></li>
    <li class="t_s_li"></li>
</ul>
```

THE JS/JQUERY

```
$(function(){
$(".spire-menu").hover(function(){
  $(this).find(".menu-item").fadeIn();
}
                ,function(){
                    $(this).find(".menu-item").fadeOut();
                }
               );        
});

$(".spire-menu").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
$(this).find('.box').fadeToggle(100);
});
```

Very sorry if this is a real noob question but we all have to start somewhere!

Any advice or help is great!

Thank you ,

-Valdis

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Comment: Other people posted good solutions, but also don't forget to put display:none to your .course_type_text otherwise it will show on load. http://codepen.io/barrigaj/pen/wkAgG

Comment: @barrigaj Thank you! You solved my second issue of the text being there at first! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `display:inline-block` to get side by side the `li` elements you can use this on your class `t_s_li`:

```
.t_s_li {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

The demo **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jHbBq**

For default the `vertical-align` for inline-block elements is `baseline`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved it for me! Thank you once again.

Comment: one other question ; now they don't move however the text is there at first until you hover over it and it disappears. Is it possible to have the text hidden in the beginning?

Comment: Just apply `display: none;` to your text

Comment: @ValdisBarrett i was not here ... like RononDex say just apply `display:none` on the class of the text

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: absolute;` to your `.course_type_text` in the css

This prevents the div from altering the layout.

You could then even remove the fixed with you are adding to that class, because it will just overlap all other html elements

Also change your hover function to this:

```
$(".t_s_li").hover(function(){
  $(this).find(".course_type_text").stop(true, true);
  $(this).find(".course_type_text").fadeIn();
  }
  ,function(){
      $(this).find(".course_type_text").stop(true, true);
      $(this).find(".course_type_text").fadeOut();
  }
);
```

This will prevent queuing the animations when you move fast over it with the mouse several times.

See here for demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fICiD

Comment: And add top: 70px; to display the text beneath the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
float: left;
```

to your `.t_s_li` class

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLIbz

Or what Dank and RononDex suggested... this is just another way to do it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Apply `float:left` to `.t_s_li`

like this,

```
.t_s_li {
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your css:

```
.course_type_text {
  float: left;  /*<-----added here*/
  width:75px;
  color:white;
  font-size:0.85em;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:0.5em;
  margin-left:-0.15em;
  font-family:"Open Sans" , arial;
  font-weight:400;
  display:block;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/3e2nL/)